# RSpec - how to exclude spec files in subdirectory?

Tags: configuration, rspec, directory

Say I have the following `spec` subdirectories:

```
lib
models
observers
workers
```

In the spec_helper.rb file, how do I tell rspec to exclude all spec files in the lib subdirectory?

```
Spork.prefork do

  ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'

  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.mock_with :rspec
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

    config.before(:suite) do
      DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    end

    config.before(:each) do
      DatabaseCleaner.start
    end

    config.after(:each) do
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
    end

    config.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values = true
    config.filter_run :focus => true
  end

end

Spork.each_run do
  FactoryGirl.reload
end
```

FYI - I'm using guard to auto-reload tests.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to exclude but you can include a list in guard like this:

```
guard 'rspec', :spec_paths => ['spec/models', 'spec/workers', 'spec/observers'] do
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is [Exclusion Filters](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/filtering/exclusion-filters):

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  # declare an exclusion filter
  c.filter_run_excluding :broken => true
end

describe "something" do
  it "does one thing" do
  end

  # tag example for exclusion by adding metadata
  it "does another thing", :broken => true do
  end
end
```

exclusion flag can be applied to `describe` and `context` too.

Also, [this](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-3/docs/filtering/run-all-when-everything-filtered) is useful config option:

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true
end
```

So if everything in `/lib` is excluded, you will still be able
to run specs manually with `rspec spec/lib/`